# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined vue when npm run production

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I create app with Laravel and Vue. When I run `npm run dev` every thing is run. But when I run `npm run production` there are an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at i (bootstrap:83)`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please have a look at [this topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and update your question with more details like the `bootstrap.js` file that seems to be the one that is throwing the error